# Do not match string if it contains a specific word

Tags: regex, pcre

I've been at this problem for a while now, and every website on earth tells me the same answer which doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to match any string as long as the string `data:` is not present at the beginning. Ultimately I am trying to stop people from injecting data URIs into my parser. The best pattern I've come up with so far is:

`((?!data:).*)`

But it doesn't actually work. At all.

https://regex101.com/r/oR3iD8/2

Comment: `data:` anywhere else in the string is okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the simplest "pattern", would be...

```
data:
```

Heh, if this matches, you discard the string. If it doesnt't match, you take the full input string. Why even use regexes, a simple "string contains" function will do.

If you *really* want a regex solution, use a lookahead:

```
(?s)\A(?!.*?data:).*
```

But really, why bother?

Comment: Well that was fast! Thanks for your help, this seems to work. :)